# My app.js code changes doesn't appear in when i check console. how fix it?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5

I have changed app.js code and hit this command "npm run watch" but when i check console changes not affect to app.js how fix this?

[app.js code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqpBT.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTeoK.png)

Comment: did you clear the browser cache and a hard reload??

Comment: i have cleared the browser cache. but not try for hard reload. how hard reload?

Comment: If using Chrome on mac `Command + Shift + R` and windows `Ctrl + Shift  + R`

Comment: I tried hard reload but same error

Comment: You are sure making changes in app.js from `resources` directory right? You are not editing compiled `app.js` directly? Add your webpack file code here.